# Birthday problem using given Theorems

Tags: probability, cryptography

Given a set of n elements the number of random samples until a collision is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\pi \cdot n/2})$.

I have to give a proof using the following theorems:

- $1-x<=e^{-x}$
- $\int_{0}^{N} f(x) dx \leq\sum_{i=0}^{N}f(i)\leq\int_{0}^{N+1} f(x) dx$
- $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$

So I calculated

$$\begin{align} 
P(\text{no collision when drawing k samples}) \\
&=   1-\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}1-i/n \\\\\\
&\geq 1-\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} e^{-i/n}
\end{align}$$

This is the point where I stuck.I tried using the series representation of the exponential function or adding the exponents using the sum of natural numbers but both didn't bring me further.